# Python dateparser error, AttributeError: "safe_load()" has been removed, use

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Today while I was trying to build my application without any changes made to old code just added logging and found below error by surprise.

```
 File "/app/search/parsers.py", line 9, in <module>
    import dateparser
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateparser/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    _default_parser = DateDataParser(allow_redetect_language=True)
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateparser/conf.py", line 84, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateparser/date.py", line 290, in __init__
    available_language_map = self._get_language_loader().get_language_map()
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateparser/languages/loader.py", line 21, in get_language_map
    self._load_data()
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateparser/languages/loader.py", line 39, in _load_data
    data = SafeLoader(data).get_data()
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 108, in get_data
    return self.construct_document(self.composer.get_node())
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 123, in construct_document
    for _dummy in generator:
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 629, in construct_yaml_map
    value = self.construct_mapping(node)
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 427, in construct_mapping
    return BaseConstructor.construct_mapping(self, node, deep=deep)
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 242, in construct_mapping
    value = self.construct_object(value_node, deep=deep)
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 145, in construct_object
    data = self.construct_non_recursive_object(node)
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 179, in construct_non_recursive_object
    data = constructor(self, node)
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateparser/utils/__init__.py", line 192, in construct_yaml_include
    return yaml.safe_load(get_data('data', node.value))
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/main.py", line 1105, in safe_load
    error_deprecation('safe_load', 'load', arg="typ='safe', pure=True")
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/main.py", line 1037, in error_deprecation
    raise AttributeError(s)
AttributeError: 
"safe_load()" has been removed, use


  yaml = YAML(typ='safe', pure=True)
  yaml.load(...)


instead of file "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateparser/utils/__init__.py", line 192

        return yaml.safe_load(get_data('data', node.value))

script returned exit code 1
```

Package versions:

```
dateparser==0.6.0
PyYAML==5.4.1
```

Can someone help what exactly changed out of sudden causing this error?

Comment: What version of yaml do you have?

Comment: @ewokx I have updated the question with package versions.

Comment: Your dateparser version is 6 years out of date and incompatible with your PyYAML version.

Comment: @user2357112 Ok but why did it started failing today? without any changes in code? Like out of sudden.

Comment: @Avi: Probably some update or other environment change.